# NGINX configuration for gunicorn and prerender.io

Tags: nginx, gunicorn, prerender

I am currently serving my website using Nginx and Gunicorn.
In particular, Nginx is serving static files and Gunicorn is serving rest-api.
This is my current Nginx configuration:

```
worker_processes 2;

user nobody nogroup;
# 'user nobody nobody;' for systems with 'nobody' as a group instead
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 1024; # increase if you have lots of clients
  accept_mutex on; # set to 'on' if nginx worker_processes > 1
  # 'use epoll;' to enable for Linux 2.6+
  # 'use kqueue;' to enable for FreeBSD, OSX
}

http {
  include mime.types;
  # fallback in case we can't determine a type
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined;
  sendfile on;
  proxy_connect_timeout       300;
  proxy_send_timeout          300; 
  proxy_read_timeout          300;
  send_timeout                300;
  upstream app_server {
    # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
    # to return a good HTTP response

    # for UNIX domain socket setups
    # server unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;

    # for a TCP configuration
    server 127.0.0.1:8181 fail_timeout=0;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name  www.miralytics.social;
    return 301 https://www.miralytics.social$request_uri;
}

  server {
    # if no Host match, close the connection to prevent host spoofing
    listen 443 default ssl;
    ssl_certificate      /certificates/fullchain1.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /certificates/privkey1.pem; 
    server_name www.miralytics.social;
    gzip on;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_types text/plain text/html text/xml text/css application/x-javascript image/png image/jpeg application/javascript application/octet-stream application/json;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_min_length 0;
gzip_comp_level 9;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    proxy_connect_timeout       600;
  proxy_send_timeout          600;
  proxy_read_timeout          600;
  send_timeout                600;
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # path for static files
    root /home/edge7/UIBackend/dist;

    location ~ ^/(images|javascript|js|css|flash|media|static)/  {
      root    /home/edge7/UIBackend/dist;
      expires 1d;
    }

    location /auth/register {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
      # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8181;
    }
    location /auth/login {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
      # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8181;
    }
    location / {
      # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
      try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }


    location @proxy_to_app {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8181;
    }

  add_header Cache-Control no-cache; #(no cache for testing reasons)


  }

}
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/thoop/8165802) the official prerender configuration for Nginx, but as you can see it does not fit my current configuration because I already have @proxy_to_app.
Has anyone experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just modify your config a little bit so where you have this:

```
location / {
  # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
  try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
}
```

You would want to change that to:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token YOUR_TOKEN;

    set $prerender 0;
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "googlebot|bingbot|yandex|baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
        set $prerender 1;
    }
    if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
        set $prerender 1;
    }
    if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
        set $prerender 0;
    }
    if ($uri ~* "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff|svg|eot)") {
        set $prerender 0;
    }

    #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    if ($prerender = 1) {

        #setting prerender as a variable forces DNS resolution since nginx caches IPs and doesnt play well with load balancing
        set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
        rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
        proxy_pass http://$prerender;
    }

  # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
  try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Prerender (indeed!),
That works fine.
I got now a different problem. I updated my try_files like this:
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html @proxy_to_app; 
index.html is important to allow users to refresh pages (Angular routing), the problem is that I cannot submit on your https://prerender.io/ page other pages than my initial page. I hope the question makes sense

Comment: You shouldn't need to change the @proxy_to_app now that the prerender config is above that. Could you send us an email at support@prerender.io with some more info on your config file so we can help diagnose that problem?

Comment: I am going to accept the answer as it solves my original problem.